# Which classifier to use?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a scenario in which I have many (100k+) files containing lines of text. I would like to know if the text contains "Storage" information and the type of it (If available). However, the text in these files are unstructured. "Storage" information has no fixed format. They can range from:

1. "Store at X to Y degree Celsius."
2. "Keep at room temperature"
3. "Refrigerate at X temperature."
4. "Freeze at X temperature"

and combinations of the above.

There might also be spelling error in the data. Eg, Store might become "Stor",Stoer","Sto" or even be absent.

Is there way to use machine learning classifiers to find files containing "Storage" information and split them into the categories:

1. Room Temperature
2. Refrigerate
3. Freeze

I have seen a few classifier algorithms but have no idea how to get started with them. I am new to machine learning.

Comment: It seems like 90% of this problem is solved using `grep`

Comment: That is what I thought at first but consider the scenario Store at -15 degree Celsius and Freeze at X temperature has the same meaning. How would I differentiate between the two?

Comment: Some of the text might say "before opening product, store at room temperature. After opening, Freeze at 0 degree Celsius." I would need to care only about what happens before opening the product.

Comment: @Sycorax Would I be able to use grep for data that is inconsistent: Where there would be spelling errors, For example, "Store at X to Y" might be "Ster at X to Y" which would be missed. The Data in the text is from OCR so it is not always accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could run through a sample of the reports coming in, see what kind of words are used and the most common spelling errors, and use that as a base. You most likely can't find all possible errors but the most widely misspelled words could be a good place to start.

I have no clue on even the start of machine learning, however coming at this from another perspective might be able to help. If you can build a dictionary of the most common misspellings, the machine should be able to learn from there.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. Thank you. I shall try it out.